# Is this equality true in a triangle?

Tags: geometry

[image: triangle]

In the triangle above :

$$XY \parallel BC$$
$$XO \parallel AC$$

Now, Is it true?

$$\frac{OX}{YC} = \frac{OY}{BY}$$

Comment: The triangles $\triangle(OYX)$ and $\triangle(YBC)$ are obviously similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are essentially asking if the two triangles $\triangle(OXY)$ and $\triangle(YBC)$ are similar.

This is true as $$XY \| BC\\XO \| AC \implies XO \| YC$$ and we also obviously have $$OY \| BY$$ Each line in $\triangle(OXY)$ has a corresponding parallell line in $\triangle(YBC)$, and consequently the two triangles are similar.